# How can I get around that Blank Screen?

Tags: boot, system-installation

This is my first experience with any linux product. I successfully installed ubuntu 12.10 i386 version. But now I only get a blank screen.

My computer specs are

> Pentium 4 (1.8 GHz) 1.25GB-RAM and no graphic card.

Comment: please somebody help me